# Email based interaction with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems

I need some gem that will allow users to interact with rails app through email, without need   to register. For example: I publish something for sale, accompanied with email, and all of controls (CRUD, and submitting) I get on my email as links (delete, update, and so on). I'll like to, somehow connect it to devise, with opportunity of further registration using the same email with shopping history.

To publish something(services or products) for sale User has to fill:

name, email (validates unique), phone. That may or may not be used for future registration using devise.

in the same form may be: pictures, description, and other fields of product.........

the idea is to store: id, name, email, phone in user db without password, or be somehow pending for registration

Comment: You need to clarify this question. It's vaguely defined. In the comment to mickula, you are suddenly requirering devise integration.

Devise already supports authentification tokens, but probably not for non-existing users.

It seems like you want to authentificate users that are not even signed up. How much information do you have about these users besides their e-mail address?

Comment: sorry, I thought that there is some gem for this, and it's not necessary to add all details. The Question is updated, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own CRUD controller with authorization based on some hash that you will add to the URL. Store those hashes in the database and verify if user is legitimate to perform action.

**Warning**: anyone with the valid URL will be able to perform these actions.

Well, in comment you wrote that you want it to integrate with Devise. Devise supports login tokens but for existing users. You should then somehow virtually register them. Easiest approach would be to:

1. Include user email in the URL with some tolen
2. Check if we already have such user - add token verification here

   ```
   user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
   if user.nil?
     user = User.create(field_1: value1, field_2: value2)    
   end

   sign_in(user)

   redirect_to after_sign_in_path(user)
   ```
3. Done. User is authenticated based on the email and token included in the URL.

Comment: Thank you Mikula. But I'll like to, somehow  connect it to devise, with opportunity of further registration using the same email with shopping history. And yes, this approach is not save, and I don't want to re invent the wheel:)

Comment: @AndreyYasinishyn i've updated my answer a bit, with really easy scenario to implement